# cant get su commands entered in shell from .bat file for Android

Tags: android, adb

I need to add the commands below to a .bat file but it is stops and hung at "root@apq8084:/ #" after:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell
```

Manually I can enter all the commands below, but the batch file wont pass them over.
Please someone help me with this.

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
cat /system/bin/sh > /system/bin/su
chmod 4755 /system/bin/s
chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/unexport /sys/class/gpio/export
set -A pins 8 28 55 56 76 77 95
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
echo ${pins[i]} > /sys/class/gpio/export;
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]};
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/value;
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/direction;
done
mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you know your superuser needs a password or not.

Comment: Rowatt, there is no superuser password.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the script is stopping at the `su` command because it is waiting for a password for the superuser to be entered. Are you wanting to run all the commands after the `su` statement as superuser? If so then you can use the **heredoc** syntax and supplied your password as the first and only argument to the schell script 
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells for more details.)

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_PASSWORD=$1

adb root
adb remount
adb shell
echo ${MY_PASSWORD} | su -S <<EOSU
    mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
    cat /system/bin/sh > /system/bin/su
    chmod 4755 /system/bin/s
    chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/unexport /sys/class/gpio/export
    set -A pins 8 28 55 56 76 77 95
    for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    do
        echo ${pins[i]} > /sys/class/gpio/export;
        chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]};
        chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/value;
        chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/direction;
    done
    mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
EOSU
```

And then call it like this:

```
my-script.sh mySuperUserPassword
```